# Why does the Hartell Reservoir style pump require no venting, while the Little Giant Drainosaur does?

Tags: basement, vent, sink, drain-waste-vent, sump-pump

Why does the Hartell Reservoir style pump require no venting, while the Little Giant Drainosaur does? See links below for more info on pumps

[Hartell Pump](http://www.hartell.com/vgn-ext-templating/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=4e1e412d05ef1410VgnVCM1000001836a50aRCRD&vgnextchannel=ea9db8c011770410VgnVCM1000008101000aRCRD&vgnextfmt=default)

[Little Giant](http://www.little-giantpump.com/506065%20Little%20Giant%20Drainosaur.html)

I am having a hard time getting a sloped connection from my utility sink pump in the basement to the outdoors, so I am looking for other solutions. All advice is welcome. Little Giant specifically says no AAV valves.